# Is it possible to re render a single pass and not the whole scene again?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I'm experimenting with the values for the mist in my scene (Cycles), however each time I want to test the new values I can't find a way to only render the mist pass. This results in the whole scene being rendered again which takes a lot of time and makes experimenting with the values a real drag.

So the question is, can I render only the mist pass and then use it with the original render in the compositor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the answer is **no**, however I'm not sure why this wouldn't be possible for some passes such as *Object Index*, *Material Index*, etc.)

As a workaround, render only one sample (you can also [render at a lower resolution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3474/599) while testing).

To combine with the original render you will have to save the render to the hard drive (you may want to use `exr` to preserve other passes) and then load it back into the compositor with an *Image* node.