# How do I adjust the resolution of my render accurately? The resolution is off

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I just rendered an image with the 1920 x 1080 resolution, but when the image was done rendering it was 960 x 540.

I don't know why it is coming out different from the dimensions specified in the render, what is the reasoning behind that?

This is a Cycles Render, if that makes a difference.
My rendering setup below:

[image: render settings]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3473/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the resolution percentage is set to 50%. To fix just change to 100%. Setting is located under the resolution settings.

Comment: Wait, so you have to set a resolution, and then set what % of that resolution you want to obey? What is the point of this?

Comment: For a render preview

Comment: probably useful to do fast test renders at a low percentage keeping the same aspect ratio

Comment: @tberghuis isn't that what lowering the sampling rate is for?