# My Blender rendered pictures are pixelated

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I render my animation the output pictures are pixelated, can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3473/599

Comment: As an extreme case, it could also be that your render view is so zoomed in that you can see the image pixels bigger than they really are. Try pressing Numpad "1" Key with the mouse cursor over the render preview: it will reset the zoom to 1:1 (actual resolution)