# How to properly import Image as Plane with Alpha Channel in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, objects, node-editor, workflow

I am making an 2-D animation using images-as-planes with alpha channel.  I am using the Cycles render engine. I am using Blender 2.75.

How do i properly import 300 dpi images, with alpha channel?

Thank you!

Edit: It seems there was a glitch with the version of Blender (portable) that i was using.  I have downloaded the newest (portable) version of Blender, 2.76, and the problem is gone.  I have posted my new PNG problem to another question!  I will leave this question up because Cegaton posted a valuable link, and maybe someone can benefit from it.

Comment: I tried premultiplied!  I really don't know what is going wrong, probably something basic I am not doing right.

Comment: can you edit your question and add an image of the issue (or your blend file with a packed images?

Comment: I pressed the 'official' render button to check, and the images are completely pixelated, not at all like the way they appear in the workspace area & render.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated

Comment: I will see if i have the same problems in the new Blender, and if I do I will come back to this question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31213/discussion-between-cegaton-and-wishyq).