# Pixels in Cycles render

Tags: rendering

I'd created glass bottle filled with corks, rendered it in Cycles and I've got low resolution pixeled render. It does not look like the problem with fireflames everybody writes about: number of samples and other things does not help. :(
Any ideas?

[image: corks in the bottle]

Comment: do you have a displacement / bump map on the cork? What happens if you make a border render of that region. (ctrl+B, lets you draw a rectangle to delimit the area in question). Set the render solution from 50% to 100% or  200% - as a test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendered image looks pixelated](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated)

Comment: What resolution (image size) are you rendering?