# How do you set the rendering size?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, camera

How do you size the camera to fit the size needed on the youtube channel art? It says it's too small when I upload the image. I need to make the camera at least 2048 x 1152 pixels. It would be nice to have it at 2560 x 1440 pixels though. I tried the other questions, but it didn't make it any wider than it was before. The Y and X values under Resolution in Dimensions Under Render Settings just made the camera taller.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated

Comment: I tried those before and they didn't make it any wider for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the desired size for the rendered scene in Scene->Dimensions->Resolution:

[image]

Then render using <kbd>F12</kbd> and save the resulting image

Comment: anyone looking for answer for blender 2.8 - look this on outputs section.