# Why do I get noise on my scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, import

After importing a 3D scene from SweetHome3d (in .obj format), my preview window and also the F12 rendering result suddenly has very much "noise".
(Please tell me if that's the correct term, I'm a blender newbie)

I never saw this when working on small scenes that I created from scratch or any tutorial files. As I added 3 point light sources to the room to rule out noise due to a too dark room, I assume it has something to do with the size of the scene? Any idea how to improve the results?

This is a screenshot, you can see the problem in the upper left window:
[image]

And this is how the final result looks like:

[image]

A screenshot of light path and samples settings:

[image]

Comment: You need more samples: read: - [Render Samples set too low](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)
 - [Lights or environment not set to multiple importance](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5309/when-should-mis-be-used-and-when-should-it-be-disabled/5397#5397). Aditionally [this link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8152/what-is-multiple-importance-sample-option/8156#8156)
 - [render resolution is set to less than 100%](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated)

Comment: Are you aware that you are using Cycles render engine and not Blender Internal? (I ask because you said you feel a bit blender newby)

Comment: @Carlo: Well, I read that Cycles is better and some plugins like the "online materials library" do not work with BI. Did I get this wrong? Is BI still preferred?

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say you should change render engine (the choiche depends on your need). Just saying that as Cycles is an [unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_rendering) render engine, a bit of noise should be expected. And I felt like you were surprised by seeing it, so I asked if you were aware of not using BI (wich is instead biased)

Comment: BTW, giving a closer look at your images, that seems not usual "noise" but more "lots of fireflies". Do you have many mirroring surfaces/very strong light sources/glass shaders? Could you show your light path and samples panels?

Comment: @Carlo: I've uploaded a new screenshot with those settings. Meanwhile I'll google what fireflys are :-)

Comment: Give also a look here: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

Comment: None of those tips solved the problem. Using all of them made the F12 rendering at least look "acceptable". The preview is still noisy though.
Maybe the imported materials have indeed some kind of "default texture" which totally confuses the rendering engine. I'll try to replace floor, ceiling and walls with a simple white diffuse shader.

Comment: If the problem still persist, consider the option to uplad your file (or a simplified version of it) on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. With a more in-depth look of the scene I'm sure someone will find out the source of the noise

Comment: Indoor scenes cause tons of noise because the light bounces off all the walls and stuff. Have you tried using portals? See https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/using-portals-accelerate-render-times/

Comment: The video looked promising but I did not notice any effect on my scene.
After much trial and error I found some settings I can live with, all in the Camera settings:
1. render/device=GPU (although it sometimes crash Blender) 
2. sampling: "branched path tracing" instead of "path tracing"
3. sampling: AA Samples increase as much as I am willing to wait (64 looks ok)