# Rendered image too grainy even with 800 samples

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have my first render, the classic BlenderGuru tutorial.
[image: Extremely Grainy Render]

The RenderLayer is set, so I don't know what's happening.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sfHytqqIFKMV9VNjdKR3V2aEE/view?usp=sharing) for the blend file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What reference do you have for something being "too grainy" for a specific number of samples?  Are you just asking for advice on how to speed up the render time while reducing noise?  There are many threads on that.

Comment: It's not that noisy in my opinion. The resolution is just very very low. Especially the resolutions of the textures used for the table and the wall.

Comment: How can I increase resolution?

Comment: @MushroomSwag - You can't increase the resolution of the original texture. You need to find textures that have higher native resolutions to start. If your textures are tileable you could scale up your UV map but the texture would become smaller.

Comment: You can also render a higher resolution. At default it is set to 1920x1080 but on 50%. If you set this to 100% you will render your image at twice the resolution. This might help.

Comment: Hold on, I'm rendering it myself on 100% resolution (takes twice as long). The image will turn out great. But I don't have your textures, because you didn't pack them into the .Blend file. Your textures are replaced with pink in my render, but you will see no noise in the final image.

Comment: @Hendriks3D It takes 4 times as long. Double the resolution, quadruple the render time. That's how it works. If you count the pixels of 1920*1080, you will find that they are 4 times the number of pixels of 1920*1080/2.

Comment: No I think blender takes the half amount of total pixels with 50%. Not half amount of pixels in the width and height. That's different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/rendered-image-looks-pixelated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem mostly comes from the resolution. Blender sets this at 1920x1080 at default -which is good- but also sets it at just 50%. I just rendered it myself on 100% and it turned out much better. Your textures are replaced by mine, because you didn't pack them into the .Blend file. You should get higher resolution textures. Also, part of the reason why (still at 800 samples) it looks a little noisy, is because your light sources run extreme values. 3 area lights from which one has a strength of 50,000. Maybe if you replace the area lights with planes of the same size, using an emission shader to light the scene, it would look better.

In my version of the render I did all of that. Replace the lights, put my own textures in, rendered it at 100% resolution. I thought that the green donut looked a little weird because the frosting is using an emission shader. I didn't change it though.
My version of the render without having changed the lights and textures:
[image: Only resolution changed.]
Here I only changed the resolution.

My complete version of the render:
[image: Changed resolution, textures and lights. I also aligned the background so it would fill the full image.]
Here I changed the resolution, textures, lights and I aligned the background so it fills the whole image. Because of the lights now being planes with low values of strength on their emission shaders, the image is noiseless.

Download my version:
[image]

Comment: Mesh lighting results in a lot of noise. It is better to use Area lamps. Just make them bigger and they should reduce a lot of noise.

Comment: Well see it for yourself. The mesh lighting results in NO NOISE. The huge area lights he had put in, which are as large as my mesh lights, ended up in a noisier image. The proof is here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was struggling with this problem for so long. :)

Comment: @Hendriks3D then probably it depends on the scene. I usually try to avoid mesh lighting because in all of my scenes it resulted in more noise.

Comment: Okay good for you! Could you please mark my answer as 'correct'?

Comment: Turns out my textures were from http://texturer.com/set210/ and somewhere on http://texturer.com/sub130/?page=1

Comment: I suggest you make a free account on cgtextures.com. You can download a number of professional textures every day.