# Override range number buttons

Tags: python, interface

Many parameters have restricted ranges and if you input a value higher than the maximum, it'll snap back to the maximum value.

Examples include:

- `speed` in a fluid simulation is limited to 100.
- `energy` of a lamp is limited to 10.
- etc.

Is there any way to override these restrictions?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2832/599. This works for lamp energy.

Comment: I think others (like fluid speed and domain size) are hardcoded in. There might be some technical reason why those are the max allowed values..

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what the benefits to the code of those limits are.  From a user's perspective, they seem to get in the way sometimes.

Comment: No kidding.. :P

Comment: Typically the hard-limits are set quite high, what setting was

Comment: @ideasman42, the actual limit that was causing me an issue was the `substeps` for a Dynamic Paint canvas set to Image Sequence.  It's limited to 20, but I needed something more like 200 since the brush was making sudden jumps.  I've run up against these limits in the past, but I can't remember now which ones those were.

Answer (score 4):

In short, there is no way to override internal limits.

However blender has 2 limits per setting:

- soft-limits: which is for number button mouse motion
- hard-limits: allow you to type in more extreme values, but there still is a limit.

These let you enter lamp energy of `10000000.0` for eg.