# Number of Cuts when subdividing

Tags: modeling

When subdividing a plane I want to have 150 cuts (number of cuts) but the system does not allow me to enter a number larger than 100. Is there a way to change that ?

By the way, Blenderguru entered 150 cuts in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhYtJ_VmvXE) at about 07:30 min

Comment: For me the max is 10, either way, just do 100, and then do it again and do 50. Would that not work?

Comment: subdivide to 75 cuts, then subdivide the cluster again once?

Comment: I am doing this tutorial and there 150 cuts are entered. So I guess it must be possible

Comment: @Lukaash you can do more than 10 by entering the number on the toolbox or the F6 menu http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4FrK.png

Comment: @OldMan I don't think you can go past 100 on a single operation. you share the link to the tutorial in question?

Comment: @cegaton Interesting, surprised i've not tried that before.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/override-range-number-buttons/13654#13654  and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-set-sliders-to-values-outside-the-limits-allowed-by-their-slider

Comment: I just tested and I can do 150 and 200 no problem on Blender 2.74. I even tried higher and it starts taking long after 700ish. 

Sure you can chain the subdividing for extreme numbers, like do 5 and then 30 so that you get 5*30=150 in total. In fact for large numbers its much faster doing by factors than the whole ie. 80*10 is faster than 800.

Comment: @kheetor In 2.77 the max number of cuts is 100. I agree this is not a showstopper, but since Andrew Price could enter 150 I was curious why I couldn't

Comment: @OldMan Something did change in more recent versions of blender. Using v2.73 (the one used in the tutorial you linked) you can indeed use 150 subdivisions... Maybe it is noted somewhere in the release notes.

Comment: Okay, I guess its smart they limited it since doing it in smaller numbers is faster anyway. But sadly now you can't divide an edge into 102 equal parts since 101 is a prime number :p

Comment: It seems that they really limited it to 100 :-/ But if it's really necessary then yes, there is the way to change that. Just find the limitation in the source file, and recompile. Thank god, blender is open source.

Comment: Note **that the number of cuts != the number of subdivisions!**. A single cut subdivision operation *doubles* the number of total cuts. `total_cuts = initial_cuts^(subdivision_cuts+1)` So to get 150 cuts, do one subdivision of 75 cuts, then a subdivision of only one cut. 75*2 = 150. Doing two operations of 75 cuts results in a total of `75*75 =` **5625** cuts. Also note that a plane already has two vertices per side, so if you want the number of edge verts to exactly = 150, do 74*2 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative instead of subdividing a plane you can create a grid object.

[image]

Then have 150 subdividsions for X and Y. And on top of that you can click on Generate UVs. No need to unwrap and all of this in object mode!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a soft input and a hard input in blender.

Soft has its own max value and hard has its own max value.

you use soft when you drag,you use hard enter when you press on the value,type a number and press enter.

Usually the hard max is larger.

But the max is the max,sometimes you can't exceed it.

[image: max]

Comment: yes I typed the number (hard enter) but 100 was the max.

Comment: As I said,this is the hard max so you can exceed it.

Answer (score 2):

It was changed around June 2015 as part of a [cleanup](https://developer.blender.org/rB43f6ed908f0cb94c5a6546676c34462ba99a72ac) of parameters with very large maximum values.

I can't see any rationale behind the decision to opt for maximum 100 subdivisions, which may mean it was an arbitrary decision on the part of the developer.  It's possible it could get bumped up to something more reasonable (like 1000) in a future version.  However, feature requests are out of scope of this forum.

Comment: Subdividing can easily push your computer past what's practical, into the world of massive computing, which most users will not be able to deal with.  We've seen it happen often, when users get happy with the subsruf modifier and end up with several million polygons and wonder why the computer is not responsive any more.

Comment: Yeah, if you read the diff that's not why this was changed though.  There was a desire to move from having an insane max value (2147483647) to something more 'sane'.  However, they chose a max value of 1,000,000 for loop cuts, 1,000 for edge ring cuts and 100 for subdivide.  Clearly, adding a million loop cuts will task most machines but 101 subdivision isn't unreasonable.