# 1000 subdivisions for relief

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to use Blender to create a relief from a photo.  I am following the tutorial and he suggests subdividing the plane into 1000 cuts.  I can only enter 100.  I realize this is a "fix" that was implemented like a year ago but shouldn't we have the option using whatever our computer can handle?  I have a pretty solid, fast, PC and 1000 shouldn't be unreasonable for it.

Is there somewhere I can get the Blender version before this "fix" was implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in 2 steps: 100 then 10, or?

Comment: I'd suggest using Subsurf modifier set to Simple and increasing its subdivision level up to desired amount instead of explicitly subdividing in Edit mode which provides you with a lot of geometry that probably won't be ever necessary.

Comment: use a grid instead of a plane.Related link :https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/number-of-cuts-when-subdividing .Mr Zak is correct, you will generate a lot of mosty ounnecessary  geometry having so many vertices is going to have a big impact on the perfomance of your computer. Using subsruf will allow you to control the subdivision interactively.

Comment: Also, note that if you use the SubSurf modifier on a plane, the number of faces increases as powers of 4, e.g. `4^1=4`, `4^2=16`, `4^3=64`, etc.