# How can I connect the armature to my mesh without blender crashing?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I am trying to make the armature the parent to the mesh with automatic weights but every time I try blender stops responding and has to be closed? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm running Blender v2.76 on the cycles render

[image: my snowman blender]

Comment: You should post your blend file via blend exchange

Comment: can you post a picture with the armature and mesh??

Comment: added an image :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove subsurf modifier on you mesh before you apply the armature.
[image: remove subsurf]
Else the armature will use the subsurfed model (much more vertices).

Comment: read this post to understand what happens with high number of subdivisions: [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283)

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed this problem a couple of times. As best as I could tell it was down to either the mesh not having enough geometry for Blender to figure out the weighting or it was due to part of the armature not being 'inside' the mesh. On both occasions I was able to resolve the issue with some tweaking.