# First Complete Lockup Hard Reset of New PC

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I subdivided the pants mesh a few times to 160,000 or so faces and then attempted to return to object mode, my new computer became totally unresponsive, and I was forced to carry out my first ever hard reset of this computer.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3iO3keGWrXMMjM2VW5ENjRDWUk

Comment: I think the only remedy for this is not sub-divide your mesh that many times, or use a subsurf modifier, but it on simple and change the render to what you want, but keep the viewport low

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Does it not seem odd that a 16GB new PC with a graphics card (albeit not the most powerful) would just freeze completely under those circumstances?

Comment: It does seem odd, perhaps there is something more to this, you could try downloading the installer or the zip, but if the problem persist then you can do what I said above. And, with it being a new computer, putting it under that stress can be difficult. I know with my laptop, when i first got it, it would freeze up under large tasks but it soon got over it.

Comment: Really? I had no idea that there were any such issues with new computers specifically. Thanks very much again!!

Comment: You have too many subdivisions on the subsurf modifier. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283 Abusing the subsuf modifier is one of the fastest ways to push a scene past your computing power...