# I need more subdivision levels to apply textures

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I'm modeling a dinosaur with the multiresolution modifier but I already have 8 levels of subdivision. I needed more subdivisions in some places of the mesh to be able to apply the textures, but my pc blocks when it increases one more level of subdivision. How can I solve this problem? And then to make an animation, do I need to do a retopology?

Comment: I seriously doubt that you need such a crazy amount of subdivisions.  You will be creating an unmanageable number of vertices. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28283/1853 . Add more vertices only in the areas where you need more detail using proper modelling,  and keep subdivisions to a reasonable number.

Answer (score 1):

Having more mesh data allows you to have more detail on the surface of your mesh. The mesh data only defines the shape of the object, you don't need more mesh data to add more texture detail.

While we can apply a different material to each face of a mesh, or a vertex colour to every vertex, these options give limited results. To get more texture detail you UV unwrap your model. The UV data allows you to define how much texture detail is used by each face. Often this is used to map an image to different parts of a model, but UV's can also be used to adjust the scale of a procedural texture on different parts of your model.

By scaling up the UV's of one face you can see that one face can use more of the image than the rest of the model.

[image: giving a face more texture detail]

Comment: That's correct, but I think the OP is asking about getting more vertices in the needed areas to apply sculpting texture/surface detail, not graphical textures.

Comment: I have the multiresolution modifier. How can I decrease the number of vertices in some areas of the mesh and increase in others?

Comment: @ManuelCarreira, you don't, in that the multires will subdivide the entire mesh equally, you need to alter the base mesh to alter the detail in areas. The alternative is [dyntopo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) which dynamically subdivides the mesh only in the area being sculpted.