# cycle crashing while rendering but no error pops up

Tags: rendering

What the title says, basically.

I had issues with my pc, but I've just changed CPU, motherboard, and Hard Drive and I was able to render more complex scenes before with no issue at all. My drivers are up to date.

My PC:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700

GPU: Gtx Geforce 1060

RAM: 16gb DDR4

MOTHERBOARD: ROG Strix B350F Gaming

Using Blender 2.79

Comment: This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender and should be reported to the official bug tracker: https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: but there's no temporary solution in the meantime?

Comment: Do this crash only occurs in particular project or in every project?

Comment: I've tried also other projects that I rendered months ago with no issue and it occurs.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. If this happens in just one project and not in others, then there is something that is triggering an error, but only you would know, since we can't guess what the project is and what settings you are using. A common cause for this kind of errors is trying to generate a scene that exceeds the capabilities of your hardware. A blind guess is that maybe you have too much subdivision? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28283/1853

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

 Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.