# Blender Crashing

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, error

So, as I was going through some of my Blender files changing the render time Subsurface values from 4 to 3 and enabling the 'Use OpenSubdiv' to speed up viewport animations, Blender would just freeze and then eventually crash. Any idea why this is happening? I tried reinstalling Blender, but that did not dox the issue. This has happened more than ten times already. I've never had this issue before.

Logs:

```
Blender Version: Blender 2.79b Date: 2018-03-22 14:10 Hash: f4dc9f9d68b

Log Message:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
Read prefs: C:\Users\jaden\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
Read blend: C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\Bendy\Minifig_Bendy_Package\Minifigure\Minifigure_Bendy.blend
Info: Read library:  'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', '//..\..\..\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', parent '<direct>'
Warning: Cannot find lib 'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend'
Warning: LIB: NodeTree: 'Plastic' missing from 'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', parent '<direct>'
Info: Read library:  'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', '//..\..\..\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', parent '<direct>'
Warning: Unable to open 'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend': No such file or directory
Warning: Cannot find lib 'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend'
Warning: LIB: NodeTree: 'Plastic' missing from 'C:\Users\jaden\Desktop\Blender Files\Blender Files\Current Projects\Minifig\LEGO Material\LEGO_MATERIAL.blend', parent '<direct>'
```

Comment: Can you run Blender from the command line and then post the crash message?

Comment: It shows the usual lines and then shows some errors for some missing libraries (some materials I made).

Comment: Please show us the actual errors messages. What's your Blender version?

Comment: I'll put it in the description as it is too long to go here.

Comment: I'm wondering if these files I am using are corrupted. I was just testing it out on another file and it works without any erros.

Comment: If you enabled autosave you can find the latest version of the file before the crash (it would be named *.blend1) and use that. Be very cautious when using subsurf. It is very easy to push the number of vertices to a very high number. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283 use proper modeling and less subsurf. For the viewport you can set the number of subdivision to lower number than for rendering.

Comment: Well, the viewport level is 1 and I've used this file countless times without any issues...