# Are there really so many triangles in this model?

Tags: geometry

I have uploaded a blend file [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51737).

It's the model of an RPG:

[image]

Blender says that the model has 30940 triangles.

From looking at the mesh in Edit mode, it doesn't look ilke 30k tris to me. Rather 4k tris.

Can anybody tell what might be the culprit here?
I have already taken a look if there is perhaps a subdivision modifier attached, and I didn't notice it, but I don't think so.

I have also tried removing the dense area on the handles, but that freed only like 600 triangles. I still guess that there are some vertices lurking somewhere where I don't see them.

Edit: For a test, I have removed the "horn" at the end:
[image]

Removing this part freed 5000 tris.
I just don't believe that there are really 5k tris in that section.
Just from looking at it, I would guess that it would be 1k tris maximum, but not 5k.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Remove doubles will help greatly the number of faces (around 16k)

Comment: @Kiskit Thank you. It removed 1600 doubles. Do you have any idea where the rest might be?

Comment: Use a reasonable number in the subsurf modifier. For most models you should not need more than 2 or 3 at the most. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283

Comment: @tmighty You can redo your *remove doubles* operator with a bigger *merge distance*. Might find some complex places been merge.

Comment: @cegaton I don't use a subsurface modifier.

Comment: @Hikariztw Could you post a screenshot where I would find the Merge distance? I just don't see it, and I haven't found any video that would show it. Edit: I found it: Press T, then click "Remove Doubles" in the that tool panel that just appeared. After clicking "Remove Doubles", a "subpane" appears where one can edit the Merge Distance.

Comment: @Kiskit Please make your "Remove Doubles + Merge Distance" the answer. It did the job!!!!! After I removed the doubles from the "horn" and then deleted the horn, I could see that around 1k triangles disappeared. So the horn was indeed only around 1k. "Remove Doubles" fixed the wrecked geometry. Thank you soooo much for the great lesson!!!

Comment: @tmighty That's the reason Blender 2.80 change the name *remove double* to *merge by distance*. Do the same thing but people easily know how to use it by the later name.