# I import too big OBJ. Now program is not responding

Tags: objects

I work on my project. Then I added OBJ file. Blender barely imported it, after a long time of waiting. I was happy that file imported successfully, and I saved it. Next day I open blender it almost doesn't open. I click on anything in blender is not responding for a couple of seconds. I wanted to delete the damn OBJ object that caused all of this, but despite having the whole object selected. I could not delete the object. Blender would not respond. Is there a way how to delete the object outside of blender? [image]

Comment: You've  probably hit the point where  your computer cannot handle that much  information. Unless blender has crashed, I would suggest you wait a bit. At least as long as it took you to import the project. Most likely what is happening is that you've reached the limit of available RAM and the system is caching on disk (creating virtual memory), which is way slower access than RAM.

Comment: From the top right statistics i read: over 2GB Memory used, while only ca. 700.000 Vertices of the selected Object. Since i dont even get 1GB Memory with 12 Million Vertices i assume that the file you are using already has very very much in it before this Object was imported. Is this correct? Do you really need a scene with 83000 separate Objects? (In the unlikely case, that this is not the reason for the memory use, there might be some other reason for the large use of memory you could look for such as subdivision Modifiers with way too many subdivisions)

Comment: Maybe related? [crash when using subsurf modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers)

Comment: To add information. I have similarly big objects in other layers. Next time I would make separate files, but I want to save my work. Couldn't I just increase the memory of the file, I have 16GB RAM in my PC. 2GB memory should not by the limit.