# Blender 2.81a is slow on Macbook pro when selecting items from the Properties window

Tags: performance

I recently got a new MacBook Pro so I have more free space on my computer's memory than ever before and yet my properties window still makes blender run slowly. My Macbook pro is a new model so it's graphics card should work fine. Is it possible a setting I changed in blender could be causing the problem?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exact steps you're performing in Blender?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have an object in my scene that I'm using a bevel modifier on and when I try to manually change its properties in the properties window it doesn't update for 2 minutes it doesn't even show the inputted value until it's finished processing.

Comment: Sounds like you're setting very high values for the number of segments or you have other modifiers like subsurface already on the mesh causing a high complexity.

Comment: I see so would setting it for 100 segments be overkill?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Such high numbers shouldn't be necessary at all. Have you enabled smooth shading?

Comment: Ok got it thanks for the help I'll try to avoid overdoing it with beveling from now on

Comment: Also, I probably could enable smooth shading to limit my need for the bevel thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Read this post to understand the consequences of using subdivisions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283 the same applies for the segments of Bevel. Don't create unnecessary geometry. Your goal should be the opposite: have the absolute minimum and most efficient (and less computationally intensive) geometry.

Comment: Got it thanks so much