# Blender too slow for my new computer?

Tags: rendering, performance

I just bought a new computer and I was following the donut lesson of Blender Guru.

When I raise up the number of subdivision of the donut (Viewport) to 3, the problem starts.

[image]

I can not smoothly move or rotate a part of the donut (Only 1 anchor point!). When the Blender Guru does this in his video it moves very smooth.

The graphic card is a GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER and the Processor I am using is a Intel 8-core i7. 16GB of DDR4 RAM.

The picture below that are my settings in the workfile. As you can see, I have to bring the drop of icing towards the donut.
I adjusted the graphic card settings. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your machine should be fine for Blender, you can even improve the speed of rendering by choosing OptiX as you have an RTX card. I think we need more information around what you are actually doing, can you add a GIF to show this in more detail?

Comment: It seems that the base mesh that you're using the modifier on is already having a high vertex count, much higher than shown in the tutorial.

Comment: If you're at the sculpting stage, Andrew doesn't have a subdivision modifier on the object anymore.

Comment: the subdivision modifier at a level 3 will create 81 faces for every quad in the mesh. Be careful with those settings, it it easy to end up with a number of vertices that is larger than what your computer can deal with. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28283/92768

Comment: @RobertGützkow I am in the sculpting stage and he (and me) just applied the top icing of the donut.The sculting itself is also going to slow.
Andrew never said anything about taking away the subdivision modifier. The amount of faces looks the same.
I think I am going to start all over and see where I went wrong with the subdivision modifier. It can't be my computer. It must be me. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Neil The Optix is also set with the option 'GeForce RTX 2070 Super' on.
What was I doing?: I was in sculpting mode. Making the icing thicker. And that didn't went so smooth as in the tutorial of the Blender Guru (Andrew). In the tutorial you see a result straight away. When I'm doing it.... it goes slooooow.

Comment: Can you share the timestamp of the section in the tutorial you are up to?

Comment: @Niel The video is called: Part 5, Level 1: Sculpting - Blender Beginner Tutorial.   
The timestamp is: 14.19  
But I started all over. Because now it works fine. I must have done something wrong before.   
Thank you.