# Error, too many subdivision?

Tags: rendering, subdivision-surface, memory-management

I am trying to render a still image with a well known Render Farm service. When I upload my file it returns the error: 'Project uses to much memory while rendering. Please check for too many subdivisions.' Trying to render also crashes my machine for presumably the same reason.

Can someone please help me to understand this error and how to fix it?

My file has 2.9m verts. It is composed of a dozen or so arrays which use a set of base objects to generate their iterations. Each of these have solidify and subdivision surface modifiers.

Do I need to reduce the number of polygons? It doesn't seem like that many too me.

To do this can I apply the solidify and subsurf modifiers to all objects, and then decimate geometry? Or is there another way to get the memory usage down for rendering?

Sincere thanks if you can help, happy to upload the .blend just ask in comments please if it will help to see it.

Comment: What about textures? Are you using hi-res textures such as 2k or 4k (or more)? They could be hogging video memory.

Comment: No I don't think so, there are only two base objects, one uses a 154kb png file with bump map and shaders, the other objects' textures are all built with shaders: and include transparency, bump map and, subsurface scattering

Comment: Hmm. I don't know then. Is there somewhere where the render farm posts a list of written "limits"? 2.9M verts is a lot, but certainly not unmanageable. Maybe your file is fine, it's just breaking their "rules" so to speak. It's possible that calculating the subdivision influence is what's jamming the memory. Try applying the modifiers first.

Comment: Is 2.9 mln verts the result of modifiers or are they added on top of objects which already have that amount of geometry? Other than that maybe the problem is indeed somewhere else and not in amount of geometry

Comment: The 2.9m verts value is from the lower right on the Blender interface, so I'm assuming that's before the modifiers are applied in the render. They have not been applied in the materials tab, they are stacked. So that could be the problem... I'll test using 'Simplify' under Render properties tab, and a few other tests to see if I can get it to render.

Comment: I reduced the resolution to 1920 from 2688 (which is high I think?) and I limited the Subdivs to 2 using Simplify in the Render properties, and it rendereed in about 1 min on my non GPU machine, it looks like that is the issue, need to limit the subdivision numbers on all of the arrays... (they were all set at 5 for Render)

Comment: Read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers

Comment: many times solidify essentially doubles the geometry. without any clue what the geo looks like, i would first ask if its needed. or use dupliverts, or particle instancing instead of arrays to reduce memory use.