# Subdivision Surface Modifier freezes Blender. With each subsequent processing for seconds

Tags: customization, subdivision-surface, hardware

I am on Blender 2.83. with 8GB RAM, I5 3470 3.2 GHz, GeForce GTX 1050Ti.

I am trying to learn procedural modeling with a tutorial and I've got problems with subdivisions.

If I increase the subdivisions to >3 in my *Subdivision Surface* Modifier, the result is 860.160 Vertices. Blender freezes for a few seconds every time I change any values in Blender (eg on any transforms on any object).

I am total lost in hardware questions. Task Manager during the freeze says:

- CPU 78 %
- Memory 56%
- GPU 0 (seems unrelated)

Is there any chance for me to fix this and increase the possible subdivisions trouble-free? E.g increase RAM or change any Preferences?

I tried to decrease undo RAM Limit with no success so far.

Comment: For every subdivision. You are increasing the number of vertices.  At level 3 you are creating 386 vertices for every vertex in the original model. It is easy to end up with a very large number,  possibly beyond what your computer can handle. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers?r=SearchResults

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes its a lot going on. I wonder wich part is not able to handle it. Do I need a newer processor, more RAM, GPU or both. I would buy a new computer if necessary. But I dont know which "part " could handle more subdivisions (vertices).

Comment: More ram is needed to deal with high number of vertices. Keep in mind though, that increasing the complexity of the geometry will also have an impact on the processing time needed byu the CPU to compute things. The name of the game in 3d is optimization, try to have the absolute minimum number of vertices that works for your needs.

Comment: @no-can-do Thanks a million. The computer dealer I trust(ed) recommended a setup with 2 RTX 2080 Ti which is currently far out of budget. Now I could give + 16 GB RAM a try and hoping to learn to minimize vertices on my blender-journey and the art of optimization in the future.