# Why does Blender crash when I use the Subdivision Modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image: Tri Count]

[image: Computer Specs]

I apply the subdivision modifier to one section (The Selected Handle) and Blender instantly crashes upon applying it. Is it my computer specs or a problem with blender itself?

Comment: It's difficult to be certain without knowing more (e.g., you might upload your .blend file), but 8 GB is not an especially large amount of RAM, and the subdivision modifier increases the number of vertices (etc) exponentially (something like a factor of 4 increase per subdivision level, but this depends on the object's geometry). So, my naive guess would be you are running out of RAM.

You can also inspect the crash log to try to determine why Blender crashed: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html Or, for similar information, can start Blender from command line

Comment: I found out that I was using GPU subdivision, turned it off and that completely solved the problem.

Comment: Mike, consider copy/paste your comment into the Answer below, so that this becomes an answered reference posting.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that I was using GPU subdivision, turned it off and that completely solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off GPU Subdivision in *Preferences > Viewport > Subdivision*. In case you were as clueless as I was about where to get the GPU subdivision.

Got it from [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/199667/166825).