# Brighter SSS in Blender Internal

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm working on BI materials for my model of a highlighter. I already have a Cycles version done. The SSS in Cycles looks good. The colour of the marker is intense, almost true fluorescent. I want to achieve the same result in BI. But the result is very dimmed. Is it possible to make it juicy as in Cycles? I noticed that when I turn on Environmental Lighting in BI then it looks very nice and intense too, but this is not the point. I need a material that will look good, not the lighting. See images as example of my settings.

Also, is it possible to further strengthen the BI mesh lights? They are already at 2, which is maximum, but the light is still dim.

[image: Blender Internal version]

[image: Cycles version]

Comment: There are many SSS preset. Did you try them? The difference of lighting between the two scene is considerable, it makes it difficoult to make a proper comparison between the shaders. About Blender Render shading Emit strenght see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/number-button-min-max-limits

Comment: I tried all the presets, none intensifies the effect really, it changes the color and appearance but not intensity. The Emit strength of the mesh lights worked however, I typed in a higher value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some trial and error and reading the Blender Wiki on SSS, I found a solution. It all depends on the Scattering Weight Front and Back parameters. I set them both up to 1.7 and the effect is much more juicy and brighter. As the Blender Wiki explains, these parameters are responsible for how much light is absorbed or added on the front and back side of the object.