# Using higher subsurface modifier values

Tags: modifiers

I found this nice playlist of general tips. Particularly I am interested in the [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnqDqF2VeIk&list=PLlH00768JwqGl8DPE2xIVR2fFioQQoJYh) video.

You can clearly see, at about 1:50 that the author is using a value of five in his subsurface modifier. I can only go as up as 6 though, and as a result my shape is not that much smooth.

[image]

[image]

Is it something on my end, and if yes, how can I make this shape completely smooth?

Comment: Can we see the wireframe of your model? Have you enabled Smooth shading? (Tool Shelf-->Tools-->Edit panel-->Smooth)

Comment: Yes I have enabled smooth shading, by clicking the `Smooth` instead of `Flat` from the button on the left as can be seen from the image above. I am not sure if the wireframe will be of any help as there are simply too many white lines close to each other to make anything out.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2832/599. That said, I suspect the issue in your case is caused by [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3199/599). Generally you rarely need more than 3 or so subsurf levels.

Comment: No problem zeffi. I also added the blend file, thanks for the link. It is a little bit modified though. In any case I just changed the texture values a little bit.

Comment: @gandalf3 I did not know that. It seems that it indeed makes the shape a little bit more smooth. Since this has an answer, should I delete the whole question or would it be of interest for it to have an answer and remain?

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit further. Why should I apply the modifiers?

Comment: to look at the underlying geometry.. even if you don't intend to apply the modifiers in your day-to-day usage. it's just a way to inspect what's going on

Comment: Ok I think I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use higher subsurf levels by typing the values directly, rather than using the slider.
See [How can I set sliders to values outside the limits allowed by their slider?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2832/599)

However in this case it looks like the bumpiness is more likely to have been caused by something like this:
[Weird deformation between large ngon and edge ring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3199/599)
To fix it, try adding some [supporting geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6425/599).