# How do I emit particles from the opposite normals?

Tags: particles, normals

I want my particle system to be on the opposite side of my mesh, but I can't flip the normals or that would mess up my other particle systems on the same mesh. How can I emit the particles from the opposite normals?[image: where the particles are]

[image: where I want them to be]

Comment: Move the origin of the particle mesh downwards

Comment: What do you mean by the origin?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this,you can just set the *Emitter Geometry's* normal value, under the *Velocity* tab, to a negative number.

[image]

Normally, the slider is limited to positive numbers, however, you can just click the middle of the field and type a number in.

Here is a question about this topic:
[How can I set sliders to values outside the limits allowed by their slider?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-set-sliders-to-values-outside-the-limits-allowed-by-their-slider/2833#2833)

Comment: It still won't work. When I type in -1, still nothing happens.

Comment: Can you upload the Blend file?

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39795