# What is the workflow when using Subsurf?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

My question is what is the best approach to model an object for a realistic cinematic render when using a Subsurf modifier? Because if I may compare Blender to Photoshop, which uses layers, here all we do is not reversible. Even for the "Add Modifier", I need to apply it before moving to the next step. So for example, if I use the Subsurf, what is the best workflow if I want a realistic look? Do I need to push the values to their maximum (view=6+). What is your advice based on your experience?

Here an image to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

This sphere is perfect for me but the view (as shown on the image) is at 6. Broadly my question is how do you work? What is your workflow? Do you work with the shading smooth or keep the mesh with polygons to  modeling hard surfaces of your object and only at the end you turn your object into the final rendering with a smooth shading before applying the skin, colors etc.?

Comment: It is rarely usefull to apply the subsurf modifier (or if you do it, it is often at a intermediate step to obtain an intermediate mesh, and do something with it after) and rarely useful to push it to 6 subdivisions. In which circumstances do you **need** to apply it ?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as your [other](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63759/for-realism-should-i-use-the-maximum-number-of-subsurf-levels) question. It is better to edit the original post than to post the same again.

Comment: thanks Timaroberts. @lemon, I want to curve a plane, and the more i add view the best quality I get, so I don't know what is the number of view  I have to restrict.

Comment: @Grobby, you should describe a bit more what you want to model, adding some pictures in your question. Because, if not, you may obtain only broad answers to your specific problem

Comment: @Grobby, I have seen you edit. If you want something that looks like a smooth sphere (or curved surface) yes, use a smooth shading (from the beginning). Concerning the subsurf, just believe your eyes : to me, **at this scale** I do not really see a difference between 2 and 6 subdivisions (starting from a simple sphere). Don't select you object to see that clearly as the yellow selection line is not a part of the rendering. For the other aspects, colors, textures and lights may be the more important for the overall render quality.

Comment: If I can add an advice, as you seem to wonder too much IMO about this technical aspects, you may more care about the overall composition and about what will catch the eye of people when they'll see your scene. At some points/limits all we do in 3D modeling is fake and unperfect, so 'ambiance' and 'story telling' (even in a single image) matters much more than technical perfection.

Comment: @lemon I really appreciate your opinion.You put into perspective the 3D work. This is more art than physics and mechanics. Only the result matters. If i was insisting on this point, trying to know the best workflow, it's only because I feared to be trapped if I miss something during the creating process. Maybe I'm wrong but the work with Blender is irreversible.

Comment: Well, @Grobby, I think the most "irreversible" thing is to add to much vertices. If you keep things light, you can add more geometry (where needed), but if you go too deep, too early, things become hard to modify. Keeping flexibility (as far as you can) is the better way IMO. Concerning modifiers, they are "not destructive", so they are reversible (except two or three of them)... so do not fear to use them (and apply them only if really needed)

Comment: With a combination of low subsurf values and smooth shading you can avoid having insane amount of vertices on geometry... "Realistic Cinematic render" is such an empty term... please try to use more precise descriptions of what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sphere i see things go wrong.

Your viewport subdivision is set to 6
while your render viewport is set to 2 
Normally render is set higher then viewport, so i guess you saw to many facets thus... i'm thinking why.

More is wrong, your highly subsurfing a sphere why ?.
Go te edit mode, select all faces, go to shading/UV make sure to set faces to smooth. now the most simple sphere with a subdiv of 2 or 3 is likely enough.

Comment: You don't need to enter edit mode to smooth all faces...

Comment: your wrong smooth as per uv smooth does result in a smooth sphere with only a few faces, if your going to endlessly sudivide your wasting memmory.
only do thatif your going to 3d print